# Change font of spinner's element

Tags: java, android, fonts, styles, spinner

I would change the color of the element of my spinner. I've a black wallpaper and by default the color of that element is white. So they aren't visible. I've tried whit this code:

> android:backgroud="#FFF"

But i would change only the text and not the background. How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new xml file and like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="13sp"
/>
```

change the textSize which you want. and use the below adapter code to fill it.

```
Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.item_array, R.layout.spinner_layout);

food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

1. Subclass ArrayAdapter and override getView and getDropDownView.
2. In those methods, call super.getView or super.getDropDownView and save returned value.
3. Set Typeface for view returned at (2) (thx Sameer Segal).